# Low Performance when using EF Code First and MS SQL Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework, optimization, large-data

I have huge performance proble with EF Code First and SQL Express. Even if I use clustured and nonclustured indexes, my get methods works slowly. How can I optimize my database and what can I do for my EF codes? Any suggestions for the way I coding?

Actually some of pages has almost 100000 (one hundered thousand) row data. Some oof my pages calls for only 1 row from a table which have actually 600000 ( yes it is six hundered thousand) row data. I use indexes but slowness keeps going. Shrinking harms the indexes so I dont want to use it but any other optimization technique would be perfect for me.

Comment: 600,000 rows isn't that big of a table. The performance problem you are seeing are likely due to database issues. This is a huge topic and not one that is easily addressed in an online forum. You are talking in general performance problems as opposed to "this query isn't performing well how can we improve it". And DO NOT shrink your database thinking that will improve performance. If you don't also follow that with defragging indexes and stats updates it will have the opposite effect.

Comment: To be honest 600,000, or even 60,000,000 records, would not be overkill for a clustered index scan for one record by PK or composite key. A query like this on a capable machine would normally come back in milliseconds. I would start looking at other factors. Run a trace, if that is available, to see when the command gets to sql and how long it takes to return. Run the same query in sql admin.

Comment: What's your EF command look like? Have you run the corresponding SQL in management studio?

Comment: Actually the problem doesnt arise from EF itself. After some search in codes used in project I realize the cause of the problem is telerik kendo ui. Read methods gets all data from database and filter and sort them in C#. because database select query selects all data in 2 or 3 secs but C# filter and sort them all in about 30 secs. I will try to transform the read methods of kendu ui. Sorry for late respond by the way.

Comment: I was so inexperienced then. I know now why the codes return data consuming so many time. First of all, our cutomer's server is a shared server. So we want them to increase ram. But real problem is in our codes. Our project has no Data Transfer Layer. All layers have own models and using foreach loops takes time to transferring data from one layer into another one's model. I was known that makes our codes slower but I thought not that much. After 2 months posting this question, I added a Data Transfer Layer into project and place only models in it.

Comment: I search deeply and found that the Get method which the other developer wrote, retrieves data with ToList() method. I wrote new method (GetFilteredQuery) and retrieve the only query. So if I need to order by I anly add OrderBy method at the end of the retrived query and after that I use ToList method. This makes things faster. Only one data transfer layer and only changing Get method gives us 70% faster transactions. In our project, We use so many stored procedure. Because tables logically connected each other based so many complex rules.

Comment: So If I add a row data one of the table, it must affect the related tables. We make this with stored procedure. Rules so complex and coding them in C# makes things worse. C# coding takes so many times. So we wrote many stored procedures. Using bulk add method in the stored procedure makes thing faster than ever. I'm adding 1000 row data in only a milisecond. So the problem solved. As I get experienced, I saw the wrong codings in the project and I'm correcting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For entityframework if you don't need change tracking like if you are not going to update any select data and then update the dbcontext, you can use AsNoTracking() to tell EF not to track entity in this manner EF will not do all the fuzzy change tracking management on the entity when its retrieved from the database. Check the following article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj556203.aspx